# How come GET doesn't retrieve Rails assets from "/" href path?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, terminal, asset-pipeline

When I first load http://localhost:3000/, all my assets are loaded correctly onto the home page:

> Started GET "/" for ::1 at 2015-06-19 20:18:44 -0400 Processing by
>   PagesController#home as HTML   Rendered pages/home.html.erb within
>   layouts/application (0.9ms)   **Maker Load (0.2ms)**  SELECT  "makers".*
>   FROM "makers" WHERE "makers"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]] Completed
>   200 OK in 37ms (Views: 36.0ms | ActiveRecord: 0.2ms)
>
> Started GET "/assets/jquery.js?body=1" for ::1 at 2015-06-19 20:18:44
>   -0400
>
> Started GET "/assets/application.css?body=1" for ::1 at 2015-06-19
>   20:18:44 -0400
>
> Started GET "/assets/jquery_ujs.js?body=1" for ::1 at 2015-06-19
>   20:18:44 -0400
>
> Started GET "/assets/parallax.js?body=1" for ::1 at 2015-06-19
>   20:18:44 -0400
>
> Started GET "/assets/turbolinks.js?body=1" for ::1 at 2015-06-19
>   20:18:44 -0400
>
> Started GET "/assets/events.js?body=1" for ::1 at 2015-06-19 20:18:44
>   -0400
>
> Started GET "/assets/home.css?body=1" for ::1 at 2015-06-19 20:18:44
>   -0400
>
> Started GET "/assets/application.js?body=1" for ::1 at 2015-06-19
>   20:18:44 -0400
>
> Started GET "/assets/sky_6_hr.jpg" for ::1 at 2015-06-19 20:18:44
>   -0400
>
> Started GET "/assets/Utah_venture_centered.jpg" for ::1 at 2015-06-19
>   20:18:44 -0400
>
> Started GET "/assets/Looking.jpg" for ::1 at 2015-06-19 20:18:44 -0400
>
> Started GET "/assets/einstein-office.jpg" for ::1 at 2015-06-19
>   20:18:44 -0400

But when I press my home page *navbar button* whose `href="/"` the JPG assets are not loaded and it is white wherever pictures are supposed to be:

> Started GET "/" for ::1 at 2015-06-19 20:33:59 -0400 Processing by
>   PagesController#home as HTML   Rendered pages/home.html.erb within
>   layouts/application (0.4ms)   **Maker Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "makers".*
>   FROM "makers" WHERE "makers"."id" = ? LIMIT 1**  [["id", 1]] Completed
>   200 OK in 9ms (Views: 8.0ms | ActiveRecord: 0.1ms)

The CSS and JS seems to be loaded, but it doesn't show up in terminal. Also, if it makes a difference, the `Maker Load (0.1ms)` is **purple** with http://localhost:3000/ and is **blue and bold** with `href="/"`.

In order to correctly load the home page, I must refresh the page or go to http://localhost:3000/ myself.

Shouldn't a simple `href="/"` be the same as going to http://localhost:3000/?

Comment: The purple and blue and bold thing is just something the terminal uses to help us see that there are different queries being made to the db. The color alternates on each query. `href="/"` should be going to `http://localhost:3000` and it is, as you can see that both methods go to the same `PagesController#home`. If you are at `http://locahost:3000` and you click your navbar button, does the JPG get loaded?

Comment: Can you try using `href="<%= root_path %>"` instead?

Comment: @forthowin it gives me a "NameError in Pages#home" and says "undefined local variable or method 'root_path' for...
In my routes.rb tho I still have: get '/' => "pages#home"

Comment: Should I change my routes.rb file to incorporate root_path?

Comment: Do you have `root 'pages#home'` in your route.rb?

Comment: I changed my routes.rb file to incorporate root_path by putting: `root :to => "pages#home"` instead. That solved the NameError but not the initial error. TO CLARIFY, JPG does not get loaded when I click the navbar home button, but does get loaded if I refresh the page.

Comment: Where are the JPG stored, how are you displaying them, and what does the home action look like?